# i want to ask about Google App Script js is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

**Problem 1:**

Following is the snipet of a code it takes values from cells in function parameters and process them .

```
function functionName(Parameter1,Parameter2,ParameterOutput)


{ 
  Parameter1.substr(0, 4);


  Parameter2.toString();


...........


...........

Return ParameterOutput;

}
```

Parameter1 has digits 544578613

I want to retain only first 4 digits but none of the inbuilt functions are working

```
.toString()
.substr(0, 4)
.substring(0, 4)
```

or any other, none of them are working.
It still gives output 544578613

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

**Solved by adding folling in the function**

var app = SpreadsheetApp;

## var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

**Problem 2:**
Second problem is that i checked duplicates in a row by following function. It is perfectly working on first sheet.
But i want to modify it for second sheet PLEASE help how can i implement it on second sheet.

image has the function plz click
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eWE8.jpg)

=======================================

**Problem 3:**

I have function that takes data from column. Runs 1st For loop to retain only first 9 characters. Runs 2nd loop to to pick data from row 1, Runs 3rd nested loop to find dublicates. The problem is that the column has 1400 rows so 2nd loop runs 1400 times & 3rd nested loop runs 1400-minus-minus times with each iteration of outer loop.

It takes a lot of time and google returns Execution Time out error.
Google is very slow to perform this task. How can this be solved ?

This function runs fine for rows upto 500

Comment: If you have a second problem don't post it here editing your question. Go ahead and create another post to ask it there.

Comment: I think you maybe have misinterpreted how StackOverflow works. Please refer [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should not be posting multiple questions inside a single post. Whenever you encounter new problems with your code please go ahead and post them as new question where I'm sure someone would be willing to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using `substr()` instead of [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). What is your source on using `substr`.

I just tried a simple example and for me getting the 4 first digit with the correct method (`substring`) worked fine.

```js
function test(){
  var a = "2020notimportant";

  var result = a.substring(0, 4);

  Logger.log(result);

}
```

> **`2020`**

Try to use the correct method and see if that works.

---

This of course can be used with the google sheets cells creating a custom function with very little adjustment.

```js
function TEST(input){
//  var a = "2020notimportant";
  Logger.log(input);
  var a = input.toString(); // Convert to String before `substring`

  var result = a.substring(0, 4);

  Logger.log(result);

  return result;

}
```

See that I have used `toString` before `substring()` in case the input parameter is non-String. Here you can see an example of this working in some cells:

[image: Example of TEST Function]

Comment: I have tried everything .substr() .substring() .toString()
You are taking value from a variable but im taking the value from excel cell

Get the value from excel sheet to your function Parameter & see it will not work.

Like this;

function test(ParameterInput){  var a = ParameterInput;  var result = a.substring(0, 4); Logger.log(result);

}

Comment: I edited my question to show you that this does work using cell parameters. If you still have a problem consider giving more information about your problem, sharing the spreadsheet with example of input and expected output. Also watch out for the type of input. Otherwise I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: yes i used that before on my original sheet, here i made it look simple.
Parameter1..toString().substr(0, 4);

Comment: But i found the solution by adding following in the function top, and the inbult functions started working 
var app = SpreadsheetApp;  
var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by these. Could you maybe post/explain your solution so other people may benefit from it?

Comment: i have resolved most of my problem though some little bit glitches ive to usderstand and resolve yet. Google App Script server is Very Slow i made a function that read write data in a coulumn about 10 times but the process takes about 5 minutes or Google return errors saying Maximum Execution time reached

Comment: i will post detailed review and answer when this project is finished.

Comment: Right now i have a Problem 3